# Rails 3.1rc4 + Rack: has something changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can't seem to use a simple rack middleware with Rails 3.1 (rc4).  Is something missing?  Here's how I built my app:

```
$ rails new skel192 -G -O -T
```

I add this line at the end of `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rack-contrib'
```

I add these lines to `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'rack/contrib'
...
config.middleware.use Rack::NotFound.new('public/404.html')
```

*[NOTE: I'm not really planning to use `RackNotFound`, I was trying to use the simplest middleware I could think of.]*

Then for good measure:

```
$ bundle install
...
$ bundle update
...
```

FYI:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.0.rc4
```

But when I run:

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0.rc4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `const_defined?': wrong constant name #<Rack (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:527:in `block in initialize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:549:in `yield'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:549:in `default'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:549:in `[]'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:24:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `block in build'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `inject'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/work/tech/external/lb/skel192/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/work/tech/external/lb/skel192/config.ru:4:in `require'
        from C:/work/tech/external/lb/skel192/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from C:/work/tech/external/lb/skel192/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from C:/work/tech/external/lb/skel192/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why `Rack::NotFound` and other `rack-contrib` middlewares are failing with Rails 3.1 but I did learn something else:

[Sinatra 1.2.x does not play well with Rails 3.1](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/325).  Switching to Sinatra 1.3.0.e eliminated some *other* problems I was experiencing with my own middlewares.

To install:

```
$ [sudo] gem install sinatra --prerelease
```

Then update your middlewares' dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of `Rack::NotFound`, so in `application.rb` you'll need to put:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::NotFound.new("/path/to/404.html")
```

Comment: You're right (upvote!) but it still doesn't work for me.  I am updating my question to incorporate your suggestion.  It still seems to be some problem with Rack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer to your question, but Rails does not *officially* support Ruby 1.9.1, only 1.8.7 and 1.9.2.

EDIT: After looking at the path, are you using 1.9.1 or 1.9.2? The gem seems installed in 1.9.1

Comment: I use both Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2.  I use `rvm` on Linux and `pik` on windows to switch between Rubies.  The "1.9.1" you see in the paths is just how Ruby 1.9.2 names things (not sure why).  If you install 1.9.2 you can see for yourself.

Comment: When I use rvm with gemsets, I don't see 1.9.1 in my gem paths. This problem happens on Linux as well? Based on your answer below, are you using Rails in conjunction with Sinatra?

Comment: I have never install Ruby 1.9.1 on any platform.  I really have no clue why that name appears in any paths, perhaps this is something specific to Windows?.  Yes, my goal is to get my Sinatra middleware components working.  But as a test I used Rails 3.1 with Ruby 1.9.2 to generate a skeleton app to which I added a single Rack::NotFound middleware (no Sinatra).  My Q was about this simple setup.

Comment: I updated my Q (and re-run my tests) to include exact Ruby and Rails version.